# Azure Data Factory Dataflows - dynamic sink paramterers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working on dataflows that will handle my dimensions load. 
I wanted it to be as parametrized as it can be so i created generic source and sink (both Azure Synapse).
In debug settings of dataflows i can put requested values (tableName and schema name).
It is working for source without issue however i have no idea why but sink is not reading values

I got 
Connection failed
{ "Message": "No value provided for Parameter 'tableName'" } - RunId: 27be90a3-294a-48fa-93f0-d3fc2d6df3f5
but in debug parametes it's provided.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

[Debug settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r74EZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue:

[image]

Then i configured default value in the sink dataset parameter to solve the issue:

[image]

Comment: It's still not wroking for me, i'll give more details once i have few min to spare but even with default value problem was that it was working for 1 table (the one with default value) but when i added this as second sink and used diffrent parameter in debug it still was shooting errors.